# How to combine legends from different ggplot after extracting via get_legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

(EDIT: Removed original code and added reproducible example.)

I have two ggplot2 `geom_tile` plots.

Both have a legend.

- The first one has one gradient scale.
- The second one has two  gradient scales.

Now I extract the legends from both plots via `cowplot::get_legend()`. The aim is to merge them to one legend and add it to the right of the composed final plot.

Then I try to combine them via: `cowplot::plot_grid(legend1, legend2, ncol = 1, align = "v")`.

The problem is, that there is a large (EDIT: actually scaling) space between `legend1` and `legend2` (see figure below). I tried to remove margins of the legends via `theme()` when generating the initial `geom_tile` ggplots, but was not successful.

This there a way to completely "unwrap" the extracted legends and then stack them vertically afterwards into one ggplot figure?

Minimal example to showcase my problem:

```
m <- matrix(round(rnorm(200), 2), 10, 10)
colnames(m) <- paste("Col", 1:10)
rownames(m) <- paste("Row", 1:10)

df <- melt(m)
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "value")
df2 <- df
colnames(df2) <- c("x", "y", "value2")

library(ggnewscale)

ggplot1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()

legend1 <- cowplot::get_legend(ggplot1)

ggplot2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value2)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() + 
  geom_tile(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value))

legend2 <- cowplot::get_legend(ggplot2)

library(cowplot)
cowplot::plot_grid(legend1, legend2, ncol = 1, align = "v")
```

And here the result. The gap between the first scale and the second is too large -- what I learned just now, it that this large gap is being scaled according to the total size. So it seems to not be fixed:

[image]

Comment: (1) Please provide a reproducible question, reducing complexity to just what is required. (2) If you're going to try to mask legend headers for privacy reasons, you need to _mask_ them with something that does not have an alpha channel below "opaque". Three of the four titles in your image are clearly distinguishable (and with nothing that seems to be sensitive?).

Comment: Also, please identify where `get_legend` and `plot_grid` are sourced from, I don't think it's `ggplot2`.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks much. Will do accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to arranging plots it's always worthwhile to consider `patchwork` as an option. In your case you could use `guides="collect"` to arrange the legends without the need of extracting them first. However, at least for your example data one minor hack is necessary to show all legends, i.e. we have to add a space to the name of one of the `value` legends to prevent that they get merged.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
  geom_tile()

p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data = df2, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value2)) +
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill() + 
  geom_tile(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y, fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_continuous(name = "value ")

library(patchwork)

p1 / p2 + plot_layout(ncol = 1, guides = "collect")
```

[image]

**DATA**

```
set.seed(123)

m <- matrix(round(rnorm(100), 2), 10, 10)
colnames(m) <- paste("Col", 1:10)
rownames(m) <- paste("Row", 1:10)

df <- reshape2::melt(m)
colnames(df) <- c("x", "y", "value")
df2 <- df
colnames(df2) <- c("x", "y", "value2")
```

Comment: Thanks! But does not work for me :( My design is more complex and I do not understand where the problem is. I'll get back to you.

Comment: In the end your contribution brought me on the right track. I have still horizontal spaces between subplots I do not understand but I will either remove them later manually or work on it as soon as I have done the rest of the analysis. Thanks much!

Comment: I actually have a follow-up question; do you know of a way to plot the two legends in two columns? I have 6 legends since I have more plots, but the principle should stay the same I guess?

Comment: Edit: the three legends I mean...